# Use variable value in @each

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I want to use a variable value in @each: to create classes for different states.
But SASS don't use value, it's put in variable name.

Have this SASS syntax:

```
$success: green;
$warning: yellow;
$danger: red;
$information: steelblue;

@mixin theme ($color) {
  &:checked {
    background: $color;
  }

@each $theme in success, warning, danger, information {
  .checkbox--#{$theme} {    
    @include theme($theme);
  }
}
```

Instead of using $warning value, mixin will create

```
color: warning
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no dynamic variable names in SCSS, but you could use a [Map](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps) instead:

```
$success: green;
$warning: yellow;
$danger: red;
$information: steelblue;

@mixin theme ($color) {
    &:checked {
        background: $color;
    }
}

$themes: (
    success $success,
    warning $warning,
    danger $danger,
    information $information
);

@each $theme, $color in $themes {
    .checkbox-#{$theme} {
        @include theme($color);
    }
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness, if you are using a really old version of SCSS that doesn't support them, you can use a nested [Lists](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) and the [`nth`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method) function.

```
...

$themes: (
    (success $success),
    (warning $warning),
    (danger $danger),
    (information $information)
);

@each $pair in $themes {
    $theme: nth($pair, 1);
    $color: nth($pair, 2);

    .checkbox-#{$theme} {
        @include theme($color);
    }
}
```

Both will produce the same output:

```
.checkbox-success:checked {
    background: green;
}

.checkbox-warning:checked {
    background: yellow;
}

.checkbox-danger:checked {
    background: red;
}

.checkbox-information:checked {
    background: steelblue;
}
```